# Error while reading multiple records to compute the shortest distance between points

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, algorithm

I'm trying to code this pseudo-code but the result is not correct.
this is the pseudo-code :

```
total_distance = distance(student(1), school)
For i = 1 to m-1 do (m is the number of students in the cluster)
    Total_distance = total_distance + distance(student(i), student(i+1))
End for
```

and this is my code:

Comment: Can you post the Exception/Error and stack trace?

Comment: The program is running without exceptions but the problem is that the result (the distance that it computes and saves in database) is not correct.

Comment: actually the method (DistanceBetweenPlaces) is tested and it works correctly

Comment: What are the actual and expected values?

Comment: For example one of the records the expected value should be :21 , but sadly the actual value is :3137

Comment: I would suggest, then, that you output the computed distance (`d`) at each iteration, and also the `totalDistance` at each iteration. And maybe the lat and long that you read. Is it possible that the `DistanceBetweenPlaces` method works, but you're passing it the wrong data? When things don't make sense, you need to re-examine *all* of your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you try to read the coordinates of each student twice:
first, when you find the distance between it and previous student, and second, when you save it's coordinates in tempLong and tempLat. And I guess your input does not contain each student twice.
To avoid reading each value twice you can store previous values like this:

```
    double curLong = 0.0;
    double curLat = 0.0;
    double prevLong = (double)schoolLocLon;
    double prevLat = (double)schoolLocLat;
    double totalDistance = 0.0;
    while (readStd.Read())
    {
        curLong = Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(0));
        curLat = Convert.ToDouble(readStd.GetValue(1));
        totalDistance += DistanceBetweenPlaces(prevLong, prevLat, curLong, curLat);
        prevLong = curLong;
        prevLat = curLat;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help and I've tried this code but the result become greater several times of the expected result

Comment: Yes, now I see it does the same thing as your code... Are you sure your methods readStd.GetValue(0) and readStd.GetValue(1) return expected results?